# Display loader using Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on angular 7, I want to display loader using Http Interceptor while loading data/page. I tried different ways but it's not displaying loader while loading data/page.

I created one http interceptor service class 'interceptor.service.ts' to fetch every http request, and created one loader service to manage hide/show of loader 'loader.service.ts' then I created loader component to retrieve the data i.e hide/show from loader service 'loader.component.ts'

**loader.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {

    isLoading:BehaviorSubject<boolean>; 

    constructor() {
            this.isLoading = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    }

    show() {
            this.isLoading.next(true);
    }
    hide() {
        this.isLoading.next(false);
    }
}
```

**interceptor.service.ts**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.show();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide())
    );
}
```

**loader.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading" class="overlay">
     <mat-progress-spinner class="spinner" [color]="color" [mode]="mode" [value]="value">
     </mat-progress-spinner>
</div>
```

**loader.component.ts**

```
isLoading:any

constructor(public loaderService: LoaderService) {


}

ngOnInit(){
    this.loaderService.isLoading.subscribe(data=>{
        this.isLoading=data;
    })
}
```

Everthing works perfectly. I have two pages (doctor list i.e component 1, doctor edit i.e component 2). When i click the edit button in doctor list, then it opens doctor edit component as popup on doctor list. But, after set the common loader i got the error (i.e ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.") while open popup. I tried ngafterViewInit method in loader component. But, it doesn't worked. how can i solve it ?

Comment: What do you mean by lazy loading?

Comment: The code above looks fine, it could be an issue with the way you are (lazy)loading the components/services.

Comment: @AsimHashmi If we have 4 tabs/components on one page then it loads only selected tab/component

Comment: @P.Moloney It is calling http service on every http request but not able to get the updated value from the loader service

Comment: Perhaps if you provide your ngModel and/or a minimal reproduction of the issue, I could be of more help. I'd advise you make sure that both the `LoaderComponent` and `LoaderService` are not being lazy loaded, or are available to the interceptor when it is required.

Comment: The code above also looks fine to me, except of course it won't work anymore as soon as you have concurrent http requests.

Comment: The way I did it was without subscription. In my loader.component.html id check the loaderService.isLoading and in loader.service.ts I'd toggle the show and hide with assigning true/false to isLoading. Your solution should work too, but just an idea to give it a try.

Comment: @Dino I tried like you. Loader works properly. but when i open the popup, then i got the same error (i.e ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.") what can be the issue..

Comment: I have almost the same setup and the same issue. Everything worked fine until I added a Dynamic Dialog from PrimeNG. Now as soon as I open the dialog I get that error.

Comment: try or take inspiration from https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef{}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.loaderService.isLoading.subscribe(data=>{
             this.isLoading=data;
        })
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }

}
```

Using this ChangeDetectorRef in AfterViewChecked might solve your issue.